# How could I compute how many >x and <y conditions in my data?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I want to compute how many many **>x** and **<y** conditions in my data.

Here is a simple example.

Suppose I have data as follows.

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
data
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10   2   4   6   8  10
```

I want to compute how many values are **<=3** and **>=8** (**<=3** and **>=8** are different issues), how could I do?

If someone has any idea, I will very appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I am a fresh guy on this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10   2   4   6   8  10")

a <- unlist(dat)
sum(a <= 3 | a >= 8)
# [1] 9
```

Or a one-liner (and no intermediate variable):

```r
with(list(a = unlist(dat)), sum(a <= 3 | a >= 8))
```

Another alternative, thank you @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1,

```r
rowSums(dat <= 3 | dat >= 8)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what their actual data is like and what they're ultimately after, but instead of `unlist`ing, you could just use `rowSums`. For example, if you had `dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(10, 15*25, TRUE), nrow = 25, ncol = 15))` you could just do `rowSums(dat <= 3 | dat >= 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `which()` function (in case you need to know the column numbers where the numbers meeting your conditions appear).

```
# from r2evans' answer:
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10   2   4   6   8  10")
```

Use `which()` to find the column numbers

```
which(dat[1, ] <=3 | dat[1, ] >= 8)
# [1]  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 14 15
```

And then subset these columns from `dat`. You can either subset just one row you are interested in:

```
dat[1, which(dat[1, ] <=3 | dat[1, ] >= 8)]
#   X1 X2 X3 X8 X9 X10 X11 X14 X15
# 1  1  2  3  8  9  10   2   8  10
```

Or all rows (but in your case this makes no difference as there is just one row):

```
dat[, which(dat[1, ] <=3 | dat[1, ] >= 8)]
#   X1 X2 X3 X8 X9 X10 X11 X14 X15
# 1  1  2  3  8  9  10   2   8  10
```

Finally, you can see how many values meet these conditions:

```
length(dat[1, which(dat[1, ] <=3 | dat[1, ] >= 8)])
# [1] 9
```

Maybe this is a bit the long way, but knowing the specific columns in which your conditions for `dat[1, ]` are met might be helpful further on.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and helpful comment!